# how to pass current Combobox item in converter in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a style for comboxitem. I want to pass the current comboboxitem to converter. Style is like

```
 <Style x:Key="MyVisibilityStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibiltyMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem"
                             ElementName="ABCComboBox"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Problem is the "." is passing the object of MainWindow not the comboboxitem.

Comment: Are you going to make the selected item invisible in the drop down list?

Comment: why my "." is passing main window object in converter not the current comboxitem object?

Comment: Just once again my question: are you going to change the Visibility of a ComboBoxItem when it is selected? Then you could write a simple trigger on the `IsSelected` property.

Comment: not actually, I created this code as sample for the problem only. I need the multivalue converter for some comparision between values from two different controls but I am surprised that what "." means in binding? should not it be "this" in C#.

Comment: The "." does not mean something like `this` in C#. It just references the current [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) object. So when you bind your ComboBox to a collection of item objects, "." refers to the individual item instance. If you add ComboBoxItems directly without binding, the DataContext is inherited and defaults to the current MainWindow ínstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through `<Binding Path=".">` youre passing the object which the ComboBoxItem holds, but with `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>` you can pass the control itself.

What you also could do is passing the whole ComboBox and its selected index/item:

and in your converter you could get your ComboBoxItem like so:

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)(cb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedindex));
```

or

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)(cb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selecteditem));
```

Comment: I am making the style for ComboBoxItem. I should be able to pass the object itself.

Comment: Through Path="." youre just passing the object which the ComboBoxItem holds, not the control itself.

Comment: even though thats OK but surprisingly I am getting MainWindow object.

Comment: What do you get by using this binding: `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>`

Comment: @FlorianGl : "A ComboBox has no property which holds the current selected ComboBoxItem" is not true when ComboBoxItems are programatically added to the ComboBox, either in XAML or in code. [ComboBox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) will then return the selected ComboBoxItem instance. Note also that ItemContainerGenerator has a [ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) method, so you do not actually need the SelectedIndex.

Comment: thats correct.. but I am still surprised why . dont refer to Self. please add it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Clemens I just wanted to say, that there is no property which holds a `ComboBoxItem` object, because I thought that this is what he was especially looking for.

Comment: @FlorianGl But actually *there is* such a property, since he seems to add ComboBoxItems programmatically

Comment: @Clemens So after adding the items programmatically, one should be able to convert them like `ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem`, right? I tried this, but got an exception.

Comment: Exactly. When i say adding programatically, i mean adding ComboBoxItems, either in XAML `<ComboBoxItem>...</ComboBoxItem>` or in code `cb.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = ... })`.

Comment: I forgot `new ComboBoxItem()`, I just added the data like `cb.Items.Add(new MyData());` Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected item of the combobox by using FindAncestor:

`<Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}"/>`

Comment: so dont set value to the path property :<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}"/>

Comment: yes i tried this, both gives same object. we need to specify relativesource=self with binding.